# center tablenotes

Tags: threeparttable, tablenotes

I have a problem in aligning the table notes to the left (at the height where also the table begins) and in forcing the text to be tiny (use it for a cheatsheet). Do you have a solution?

```
% page setup
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{enumitem,booktabs,cfr-lm}% aufzahlungen mit erklärung nach Tabelle
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\renewlist{tablenotes}{enumerate}{1}

% geometry
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\geometry{headsep=\baselineskip}

% table
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \Centering and \RaggedRight macros
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx} % for well-spaced horizontal lines
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{table}
\tiny
 \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{0.22\textwidth}{@{}*{2}{C} @{}}
    \toprule
\textbf{Congenital} & \textbf{Erworben} \\
\midrule
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep]
    \item A\tnote{1}
    \item B\tnote{2} 
    \item C \tnote{3}
    \item seltene Aetiologien\vspace*{-\baselineskip} 
\end{itemize}&
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep]
    \item A
\end{itemize}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\endtabularx
     \begin{tablenotes}
     \begin{tiny}
      \item[1] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
      \item[2] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 \end{tiny}
    \end{tablenotes}
 \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

My error with the solution
[image: error]

Comment: `threeparttablex` is a package for tables notes in `longtable` and similar (`xltabular`).

Comment: Please, copy code from Overleaf, image is not readable. Also please, add list of errors, which you get at compiling this code. With my MWE compiled in Overleaf, I can't reproduce any error nor warnings.

Comment: It seems, that you have some troubles with Overleaf. Try to ask its support for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, you like to get the following result from your MWE:

[image]

The MWE for above table is:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
% geometry
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\geometry{headsep=\baselineskip}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}

\usepackage{enumitem}% aufzahlungen mit erklärung nach Tabelle


% table
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \Centering and \RaggedRight macros
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx} % for well-spaced horizontal lines
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \scriptsize
\setlist[itemize]{nosep=0pt,
                 leftmargin=*,
                 label=\textbullet,
                 before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth},
                 after=\end{minipage}}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{My three part table}
    \label{tab:...}
\begin{tabularx}{0.22\textwidth}{@{}*{2}{C} @{}}
    \toprule
\textbf{Congenital} & \textbf{Erworben} \\
    \midrule
\begin{itemize}
    \item A\tnote{1}
    \item B\tnote{2}
    \item C\tnote{3}
    \item seltene Aetiologien
\end{itemize}   &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item A
                    \end{itemize}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
     \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\tiny
      \item[1] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
      \item[2] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      \item[3] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks really nice. Thats exactly what I wanted. But I get an error. I use overleaf and at first I canged ```after=\end{minipage} ``` and placed it after ```before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}``` But it still makes an error that a ```\begin{minipage}``` is endet by ```\begin{itemize}```

Comment: @Elia - I don't get an error message when I compile Zarko's code.

Comment: @ mico could this be to some overleaf problem?

Comment: @Elia, I tested my MWE in Overleaf. It worked  fine. Probably you made some changes in my MWE.

Comment: I added the screenshot of my code (see my question above). I think I might did an error in copy paste it but I cant find why

Comment: @Elia, please copy my MWE as it is in Overleaf and then compile. If your real document has different preamble, please add to my MWE missed packages step by step and compile aster each step. At this  take care that a some package will not be loaded twice.

Comment: I dit this. It does not give me an error but color my text in red. But somehow I will find an solution

Comment: when I switched before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} with after=\end{minipage} I git no error :)